# While running steam the following error shows, what should I do now?

Tags: debian, opengl, steam, playonlinux

Error is the following

`You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6`

Playonlinux is showing

`PlayOnLinux is unable to find 32bits OpenGL libraries.
You might encounter problem with your games`

PS: I installed steam with .deb file on their site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the `i386` architecture (in parallel to your `amd64` architecture):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

then install the missing librairies. The quickest way to get everything you'll need for Steam and PlayOnLinux is probably to install `wine32`, even if you don't use it:

```
sudo apt-get install wine32
```

Comment: following error occoured while updating: http://textuploader.com/ddz92

Comment: error while updating: http://textuploader.com/ddz92

Comment: That's an issue with your mirror (probably a temporary issue). It's not missing much, the `wine32` installation should work.